# How I keep our platform token throughout the OAuth 1.0 process?

Tags: authentication, oauth, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

We have a token that we use to access and identify the user in our platform. Its pretty standard. We save it in the Authorization header property on the request.

Currently I am adding it to the query parameters in the grantUrl but the problem is that I am not getting it back when I get the access tokens. I tried to add it to the headers before the redirect - but I am still not getting it back with the access token.

How can I keep our platform login token through out the OAuth process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have a token that we use to access and identify the user in our platform. Its pretty standard. We save it in the Authorization header property on the request.

That's not very standard.  :-/

Standard is using a cookie to track what user is logged in (the cookie stores some sort of session identifier or session auth token).

You should set a cookie to identify and allow access to the user. The browser will automatically send the cookie to your server when the user hits your site during the OAuth connection process.

Comment: thats for the slap in the face... I needed it!

Comment: Haha, sorry! Sounds like you got it worked out though, which is great!